# How can I duplicate a Refile attachment between Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refile

I am using [`refile`](https://github.com/refile/refile) and have two models:

```
class UserApplication < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :avatar
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :avatar

  def from_application(application)
    # ...
    self.avatar = application.avatar
    # ...
  end
end
```

When I try to set up a `User` from `UserApplication`, the `avatar` attachment that has been associated with `UserApplication` is not saved with a `User`.

How can I duplicate or attach the `UserApplication#avatar` to the `User` instance?

Answer (score 3):

One way I found to do this is by calling the attachment `download` method and then setting a new id to the attachment. This will copy the file content and save the `avatar` to a new `Refile::File` when you save the model.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attachment :avatar

  def from_application(application)
    self.avatar = application.avatar.download
    self.avatar_id = SecureRandom.alphanumeric(60).downcase
    save
  end
end
```

I'm using Refile 0.7.0 with refile-s3.